# Pass URL path parameters from API Gateway to step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have an API gateway route with a Step Function integration.

In this step function, I need the id given by the request.

With a lambda integration I understand how to do it, but in this case I do not find any ressource. Is it possible, and if yes, how ?

Answer (score 2):

Adapt this VTL request mapping template<sup>*</sup> to add the path parameters to the state machine input.

- Replace `%STATEMACHINE%` with your State Machine's ARN
- Optionally set `$includeHeaders` or `$includeQueryString` to `false`.
- Optionally set `$requestContext` to [context key-value pairs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variables-template-example).  Use `@@` instead of quotes, as in `"{@@user@@:@@$context.identity.user@@}"`.

```
## Velocity Template used for API Gateway request mapping template
## "@@" is used here as a placeholder for '"' to avoid using escape characters.

#set($includeHeaders = true)
#set($includeQueryString = true)
#set($includePath = true)
#set($requestContext = '')

#set($inputString = '')
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
    "stateMachineArn": "%STATEMACHINE%",

    #set($inputString = "$inputString,@@body@@: $input.body")

    #if ($includeHeaders)
        #set($inputString = "$inputString, @@header@@:{")
        #foreach($paramName in $allParams.header.keySet())
            #set($inputString = "$inputString @@$paramName@@: @@$util.escapeJavaScript($allParams.header.get($paramName))@@")
            #if($foreach.hasNext)
                #set($inputString = "$inputString,")
            #end
        #end
        #set($inputString = "$inputString }")
        
    #end

    #if ($includeQueryString)
        #set($inputString = "$inputString, @@querystring@@:{")
        #foreach($paramName in $allParams.querystring.keySet())
            #set($inputString = "$inputString @@$paramName@@: @@$util.escapeJavaScript($allParams.querystring.get($paramName))@@")
            #if($foreach.hasNext)
                #set($inputString = "$inputString,")
            #end
        #end
        #set($inputString = "$inputString }")
    #end

    #if ($includePath)
        #set($inputString = "$inputString, @@path@@:{")
        #foreach($paramName in $allParams.path.keySet())
            #set($inputString = "$inputString @@$paramName@@: @@$util.escapeJavaScript($allParams.path.get($paramName))@@")
            #if($foreach.hasNext)
                #set($inputString = "$inputString,")
            #end
        #end
        #set($inputString = "$inputString }")
    #end

    ## Check if the request context should be included as part of the execution input
    #if($requestContext && !$requestContext.empty)
        #set($inputString = "$inputString,")
        #set($inputString = "$inputString @@requestContext@@: $requestContext")
    #end
    
    #set($inputString = "$inputString}")
    #set($inputString = $inputString.replaceAll("@@",'"'))
    #set($len = $inputString.length() - 1)
    "input": "{$util.escapeJavaScript($inputString.substring(1,$len))}"
}
```

* The template is taken from the [AWS Cloud Development Kit repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/lib/integrations/stepfunctions.vtl).  It is part of the [StepFunctionRestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.StepFunctionsRestApi.html#class-stepfunctionsrestapi-construct) construct's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in reading path parameters, here's a compact template you can use.

```yaml
#set($inputString = "{@requestBody@: $input.json('$'), @pathParameters@: {")
#set($pathParams = $input.params().get('path'))
#foreach($paramName in $pathParams.keySet())
  #set($inputString = "$inputString @$paramName@: @$pathParams.get($paramName)@")
  #if($foreach.hasNext)
    #set($inputString = "$inputString,")
  #end
#end
#set($inputString = "$inputString }}")
#set($inputString = $inputString.replaceAll("@",'"'))
{
"input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($inputString).replaceAll("\\'","'")",
"name": "$context.requestId",
"stateMachineArn": "${ErNameIntent}"
}
```

This will result in a payload like:

```json
{
  "requestBody": <requestbody>,
  "pathParameters": {
    <key1>: <value1>,
    <key2>: <value2>,
    ...
    <keyN>: <valueN>
  }
}
```